# Teams custom configuration settings

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to have some custom settings in the configuration tab. Every single example I found just uses the entityId of the instanceSettings. I need custom settings for my teams tab in order to be a little more flexible about configuration.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Let me know what setting you want save in Configuration tab?

Comment: string arrays, self-defined objects.. Just need a bit more than a single string 
 e.g. entityId. And I think entityId is being misused in tutorials as "settings variable", which should just be an Id for the tab as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab

Comment: You can not add additional properties in setting object. You can optionally pass required information in contentUrl as a form of query string.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. That is the point of this question. What are my options for having additional configuration properties? What are other people doing?

Comment: Currently those are the options to put your values. Either put json string in entity id or use query string in contentURL.